# How to hide Cygwin Python console window in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

How to hide **Cygwin** Python console window in Windows?

Neither `pythonw`, nor renaming to `*.pyw` does not seem to apply here, since Cygwin is a different build from regular Windows CPython build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small .vbs launcher script should do the trick:

```
COMMAND = "c:\cygwin\bin\python <path_to_your.py>"

Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set proc   = wshell.Environment("Process")

proc("PATH") = "c:\cygwin\bin;" & proc("PATH")

wshell.Run COMMAND, 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, though I did eventually switched to vanilla Python build.

Comment: If you want to pin this script to the Windows 7 task bar then you need to create a shortcut to it that actually runs "wscript.exe <path_to_vbs>".